# What is the modulus of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

I understand that the modulus of a complex number $z=x+iy$ is the square root of $x^2+y^2$, but what is the modulus of a complex function $f(z)=u+iv$ where $u$ and $v$ are functions in the reals? Specifically, what is the formula for $|f(z)|$ where $f=u+iv$? And could you add a few notes on what the modulus of $f(z)$ represent?

Answer (score 1):

if $f=u+iv$  where $u$ and $v$ are real valued functions,  then the modulus of $f$ is the function $|f|=\sqrt{u^2+v^2}$

for example, if $f(x)=e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$,  then $|f|=\sqrt{\cos^2x+\sin^2x}=1$ which tells us that the graph of $f$ lies on the unit circle.

As another example , let $f(z)=z^2=(x+iy)^2=x^2-y^2+2ixy$,

then, $|f|=\sqrt{(x^2-y^2)^2+2x^2y^2}=\sqrt{x^4+y^4}$

Comment: $f(x) = e^{ix}$ is a bad example because is a function of a real variable, not of a complex variable.

Comment: @jjagmath the original question specified only that f is a complex valued function which $e^{ix}$ is

Answer (score 0):

If $z$ is a complex number, then $f(z)$ is a complex number, and $|f(z)|$ is the  modulus of the complex number $f(z)$. It's the distance of $f(z)$ from the origin.